# incongruent results of testZeroInflation (DHARMa) and check_zeroinflation (performance)

Tags: r, zero-inflation, diagnostic

I have a count data set addressing the number of seeds being produced in dependence on the distance to a field margin (as categorical variable).

From the histogram I guessed that zero-inflation might be an issue:

[image]

So I made a model and tested for zero-inflation using `check_zeroinflation()` of the performance package and visually with `testZeroInflation()` of the DHARMa package:

```
> mod1 <- glmmTMB(seedN ~ position + (1|sampleID), family = "poisson", data = seeds1)
> test_zeroinflation(mod1)

# Check for zero-inflation

   Observed zeros: 258
  Predicted zeros: 169
            Ratio: 0.66

Model is underfitting zeros (probable zero-inflation).

> sim1 <- simulateResiduals(mod1)
> testZeroInflation(sim1)

    DHARMa zero-inflation test via comparison to expected zeros with
    simulation under H0 = fitted model

data:  simulationOutput
ratioObsSim = 1.5507, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

[image]

Both outputs indicate that there is zero-inflation. I then used ziformula to account for zero-inflation and tested the new model again with the two functions:

```
> mod2 <- glmmTMB(seedN ~ position + (1|sampleID), family = "poisson", ziformula = ~ position, data = seeds1)
> check_zeroinflation(mod2)

# Check for zero-inflation

   Observed zeros: 258
  Predicted zeros: 163
            Ratio: 0.63

Model is underfitting zeros (probable zero-inflation).

> sim2 <- simulateResiduals(mod2)
> testZeroInflation(sim2)

    DHARMa zero-inflation test via comparison to expected zeros with
    simulation under H0 = fitted model

data:  simulationOutput
ratioObsSim = 1.0073, p-value = 0.88
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

[image]

Now the `check_zeroinflation()` still tells me that there might be zero-inflation, whereas `testZeroInflation()` tells me it's OK now.

The latter uses simulated residuals. Is this why it gives me different results? And which one should I trust and why?

Further, I would like to understand what happens in the output of `check_zeroinflation()`. My model observes 258 zeros. Checking mod1, the function tells me that 169 zeros are expected. But when checking mod2 it suddenly expects only 163 zeros although I'm accounting for zero-inflation here. Shouldn't the second model expect then more zeros?

I'm looking forward to some illumination. Thanks in advance!

Comment: mod2 is a mixture model. The ziformula models only the excess zeros that cannot be accounted for by your main model (so how "position" affects the probability of zero over non-zero) I think it's not surprising that the test does not expect more zeros; those excess zeros are not inflating your main model anymore.

Comment: If the excess zeros are not inflating mod2 anymore, why is the test (check_zeroinflation) then still telling me that there is zero-inflation? Is it only working with the poisson distribution part of the model and leaving out the binomial part?

Comment: If you run the example in `?check_zeroinflation` (but with glmmTMB() rather than glm()) it has the same behavior, adding `ziformula=~.` to the model does not change the result of `check_zeroinflation()` but `testZeroInflation()` now shows the issue is gone. This output is confusing, it's worth opening an issue [here](https://github.com/easystats/performance/issues). Looks like you're fine, but you can always check the negative binomial. Is it biologically reasonable that "position" will have the effect of zero seeds in some cases?

Comment: That was a good idea checking the example! The negative binomial is only very marginally more suitable therefore I kept the example simple. Regarding your question if it's biologically reasonable - I would say in this case yes. I expect the number of zeros to vary with the position and for one of them almoust only zeros.